# RALLY Webservice 2.0 CRUD using Spring integration

Tags: rally

I am trying to do CRUD operations on rally using Rally WS with Spring integration. 
I am able to retrieve defect but while calling update, it throws error, It is not accepting any type, I tried with MAP, jsonobject.

```
    Map<String, String> updMap =...     
    updMap.put("_refObjectName", name+" TEST UPDATE");

    RallyUpdater updater = ctx.getBean("rallyUpdateGateway", RallyUpdater.class);
    String res=updater.updateDefect(updMap);

    my configuration:

        <int-http:outbound-gateway id="opgateway" request-channel="rallyUpdateJsonRequest"
    url="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/9792864541?key={key}"
    http-method="POST" request-factory="rallyHttpRequestFactory"

    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    reply-channel="rallyUpdateResponse">
    <int-http:uri-variable
        name="key"
        expression="payload" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:object-to-json-transformer  input-channel="rallyUpdateRequest" output-channel="rallyUpdateJsonRequest" />

 <int:gateway id="rallyUpdateGateway" service-interface="rally.RallyUpdater"
    default-request-channel="rallyUpdateRequest" default-reply-channel="rallyUpdateResponse" />
```

When I send a map, I use a transformer . It throws error saying expected '{'.... . 
When I send JsonObject,  it is throwing another exception.

Which format I should use?

Comment: What was the code that lead to the error and what was the error message?

Comment: Put all that into the original post by editing it (and mind formatting!) It's hard to read the way it is in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`_refObjectName` should not be used to set a name of the object. There is a `Name` attribute, and that's the one that should be used when setting the name.

The curl command below shows a payload example in json format, when updating an existing Rally artifact, e.g. defect:

```
curl --header "zsessionid:_abc123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"Defect\":{\"Name\":\"New name\",\"Resolution\":\"Not a Defect\",\"State\":\"Fixed\"}}" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Defect/17822920696
```

I can't comment on Spring specific details, but json should follow format above. However if you choose to use [Rally REST toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava), you do not have to manually build a payload like that since the toolkit provides convenience methods